# Print to excel first line of each page in pdf file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pdf, pypdf

I am new to python, only one script behind me for searching strings in pdfs. Now, I would like to build script which will give me results in new CSV/xlsx file where I will have first lines and their page numbers of given pdf file. For now I have code below for printing whole page:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

pdf_document = "example.pdf"
with open(pdf_document, "rb") as filehandle:
    pdf = PdfFileReader(filehandle)
    info = pdf.getDocumentInfo()
    pages = pdf.getNumPages()
    print (info)
    print ("number of pages: %i" % pages)
    page1 = pdf.getPage(0)
    print(page1)
    print(page1.extractText())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read pdf file page by page, split by '\n' (if that is the character that splits lines), then use the CSV package to write into a CSV file. A script like below. Just to mention that it if the PDF contains images this code will not be able to extract text. You need an OCR module to convert images to text first.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import csv

pdf_document = "test.pdf"
with open(pdf_document, "rb") as filehandle:
    pdf = PdfFileReader(filehandle)
    with open('result.csv','w') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_writer.writerow(['page numebr','firts line'])
        for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
            content= pdf.getPage(i).extractText().split('\n')
            print(content[0]) # prints first line
            print(i+1) # prints page number
            print('-------------')
            csv_writer.writerow([i+1,content[0]])
```